# Generate a Dynkin System from the events

Tags: measure-theory

> How can I generate a Dynkin System from the events $E_2$ and $E_3$ (if $2$ dice are rolled); $E_1=\{\text{first die shows}\ 1\}$
>
> $E_2=\{\text{second die shows}\ 1\}$
>
> $E_3=\{\text{sum of both dice is}\ 7\}$

If I generate a sigma algebra, then it is automatically a dynkin-system, but how to choose minimum of these sets such that it is still a dynkin-system ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can go by the definition directly.

Having $\Omega$ and the complements is easy. Your system needs to contain $\Omega$, $\emptyset$, $E_2$, $E_3$, $E_2^C$ and $E_3^C$. You also need disjoint unions. As far as I can see none of those sets are disjoint except for the trivial cases. $E_2$ and $E_3$ share $(6,1)$, $E_2$ and $E_3^C$ share $(1,1)$ and $E_2^C$ and $E_3$ share (1,6). So that should be it.

If you had to add some union, you'd obviously have to add its complement as well and check again until all properties are fullfilled. This "naive algorithm" of adding sets as necessary to comply with the definition of dynkin system will always work as long as $\Omega$ is finite or you're lucky with the set you want to generate your dynkin system of.